# Python __repr__ method not working as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, printing, repr

The `__repr__` function does not work in the following code:

```
class Minibar:
    def __init__(self, drinks, snacks):
        self.drinks=drinks
        self.snacks= snacks
        self.bill=0

    def __repr__(self):
        return "The minibar contains the drinks: " + list(str(self.drinks)) +  "And the snacks: "  + list(str(self.snacks)) +  "The bill for the minibar is:" + self.bill**

m = Minibar({'coke': 10, 'lemonade': 7}, {'bamba': 8, 'mars': 12})
print(m)
```

Comment: Could you give us the error code?

Comment: You cannot concatenate lists and strings which is what you're appearing to do here. Your question is a little vague, so some extra detail would be helpful here.

Comment: if you can also post error, that would be helpful

Comment: The term "does not work" has no meaning. The next time please use a sentence that describes the problem like: "when I try to print this object it raises a `TypeError` saying `can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`".

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify an error, I assume the interpreter does not let you concatenate a list with a string.

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "The minibar contains the drinks: " + str(self.drinks) +  "And the snacks: "  + str(self.snacks) +  "The bill for the minibar is:" + str(self.bill)
```

Answer (score 0):

The python interpreter does not let you concatenate a list with a string. Instead, you can just convert the list to a string with `str(list)` or iterate through the elements in the lists:

```
class Minibar:

    def __init__(self, drinks, snacks):
        self.drinks = drinks
        self.snacks = snacks
        self.bill = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        string = "The minibar contains the drinks: "
        for drink in self.drinks:
            string += drink + " "

        string += "And the snacks: "
        for snack in self.snacks:
            string += snack + " "

        string += "The bill for the minibar is " + str(self.bill)

        return string
```